# Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in line 2040

Tags: php, wordpress

```
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_args', 'custom_form_field_args', 10, 3 );
        function custom_form_field_args( $args, $key, $value ) { 
            if ( $args['id'] == 'billing_city' ) {
             $args = array(
                    'label' => __( 'Town / City', 'woocommerce' ),
                    'required' => TRUE,
                    'clear' => TRUE,
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'options' =>  array(
                        '' => ('Select City' ),
                'Duliajan' => ('Duliajan' )
                ),
                    'class' => array( 'update_totals_on_change' )
                );
            } // elseif … and go on 

            return $args;
        };
```

When I add the piece of code for a single city in (woocommerce) function.php, I got the following error.

[image]

**Line number 2040**-- `$field .= '<select name="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '" id="' . esc_attr( $args['id'] ) . '" class="select ' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['input_class'] ) ) . '" ' . implode( ' ', $custom_attributes ) . ' data-placeholder="' . esc_attr( $args['placeholder'] ) . '">`

**Line no 2064**-- `$field_html .= '<label for="' . esc_attr( $label_id ) . '" class="' . esc_attr( implode( ' ', $args['label_class'] ) ) . '">' . $args['label'] . $required . '</label>';`

How can I solve the error?

Comment: you got only two `implode()` calls there. What is the problem checking what you pass to each?

Comment: Check whether the  $args['input_class'] and $args['label_class'] will return the array

Answer (score 0):

`$args['input_class']` and `$args['label_class']` must be arrays so they are probably not. Your should check:

```
if (!is_array($args['label_class']) {
    // initialize to some empty array? depends on your application, what it needs to do
}
```